# WEKA training examples and testing examples do not match

Tags: string, testing, match, weka

I need to learn a classifier over training examples and to classify testing examples. My examples are long texts. I want to use a feature set in which the i'th element is the i most frequent word, for example, the first feature is the most frequent word.

My problem is that if I use string features then I can't use the classifiers I want. And if I use nominal features, I take the first feature to be the most frequent words in my training examples. And for the testing examples, the first feature is the most frequent words in my testing examples. So these features are different, and when I want to use the classifier, weka says it doesn't match.

Do you have a solution?

I want to be able to use a feature set which is the 50 most frequent words in each text, and the arff of the training examples should not be affected by the testing examples. moreover, I want to be able to use many kinds of classifiers (like smo, naive-bayes, j48 and so on).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For any preprocessing task you should use the 'FilteredClassifier'. Thereby, the actual preprocessing operation is determined based on the training set only and then applied to the testing data.

For instance: If you do discretization this way, the actual bins will only depend on the attribute values within the training data. Yet, the discretization using those bins will be applied to the testing data.